# Correct way to add WooCommerce products through another plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to program a plugin to import products into WooCommerce. I have found two ways to do that. But I think both are not really good in my case.

1. The first one is to use the REST API of WooCommerce. But I think this is rather to send requests from another server. So I think it's not the correct way in my case.
2. I also found descriptions like this http://jafty.com/blog/programatically-create-woocommerce-products-with-variations/
   But these seems very error-prone because I have to use many wordpress functions but don't talk anything directly with WooCommerce.

Is there a way to use the WooCommerce API directly? Without go through http? Or is there anything else to talk directly with WooCommerce?

Comment: You can import product directly from and CSV or XLS file that would be a good option

Comment: 1. Accessing the API endpoint *is* using the API directly, afaik, it doesn't have to be on another server. And 2. WooCommerce uses WordPress so I'm not sure what you're expecting to see in the tutorial. Products and variations are simply custom WordPress post types with specific meta. It's impossible to advise without more information about what/how you are importing, but my best guess is the API will probably work fine.